# I setup a simple upload site but uploads only work one-way when not on localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I've set up a simple upload site in php using a mysql DB, and apache.

I am using no-ip.com to hide the ip.

When my friends upload their file, I receive it on my end, but they are un-able to view it on their end.  I think this is because mysql DB isn't "server-side"?  I'm unsure what to do at this point.

some of the Code: (as you can see it's mysql dependant)

[index.php](http://pastebin.com/9CJTXAKv):

[videos.php](http://pastebin.com/rUZT0fDx):

this is all in my wamp 'www' directory, and all completely functional while it's local.

However, when online people can not view videos or images that they have uploaded.

Any help is *greatly* appreciated as I'm very new at this and simply trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is an alias of `127.0.0.1` which is your local machine, when people try and click a link to `http://localhost/file.php` they'll actually be trying to access `file.php` *on their own computer*. You need to [use your public ip](https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip) instead of `localhost`.

Comment: How would I accomplish this using wamp?  The only way to access mysql is through localhost as far as I understand.

Comment: Okay, well.  I changed the $url to include my public ip address, however, now I am getting the error "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /php/video upload and blackback/watch.php on this server.".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks AlphaDelta, I changed the $url to my public ip address, then I was getting the forbidden error from ip address' outside of lan, and I went into the 'httpd.conf' file of apache and changed the line "Require local" to "Require all granted".